# BlackBerry application encoding

Tags: blackberry, encoding

How do I change the `microedition.encoding` for a BlackBerry application?

I can only view it with `System.getProperty("microedition.encoding")`. I have tried to send it as an argument from the application descriptor `microedition.encoding="UTF-8"`, but it has no effect.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible. However you could give details on your problem, so we could try to find out some alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

As Arhimed said, your question is not so clear. It would be better if you can brief us on your problem. However if you are looking for some URL encoding you can also try this. Method:

```
private String encodeString(String hsURL)
{
    URLEncodedPostData
    urlEncoder = new URLEncodedPostData("UTF-8", false);
    urlEncoder.append("url", hsURL);
    hsURL = urlEncoder.toString();
    hsURL = hsURL.substring(4);
    return hsURL;
}
```